# Почему после сборки проекта не находит класс?

Tags: java, maven

Добрый день, собираю проект с помощью Maven, но при запуске jar выскакивает ошибка

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com4j/Com4jObject

библиотека прописана в .xsml файле в репозитории .m2 присутствует но jar её не находит в чём может быть причина ?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ton</groupId>
   <artifactId>ton</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.com4j/com4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.com4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>com4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

</project>
```

Исключение

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com4j/Com4jObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at ru.cod.ClassFactory.createSpRecordClientW(ClassFactory.java:16)
    at ru.cod.Main.сontrolСall(Main.java:289)
    at ru.cod.Main.main(Main.java:228)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com4j.Com4jObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: добавьте pom.xml в ваш вопрос

Comment: @MikhailVaysman добавил.

Comment: это полный pom? больше ничего нет?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman все библиотеки не поместились но записаны в него потому же прицепу. Хочу заметить что библиотека com4j  явлется нативной и создаёт .dll но он находиться в той же папке в maven что и jar

Comment: больше интересует раздел plugins. он пустой?

Comment: @Varg Sieg Сделайте Clean, затем Install. Покажите, ошибку.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, как создал проект кроме библиотек в pom.xml ничего не добавлял

Comment: @Владимир добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

После этого `mvn clean compile assembly:single` получите jar внутри которого все ваши зависимости лежат.

Так же можете добавить вот это. Только исправьте имя главного класса.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Тогда получите запускаемый jar.